# Excluir valores de todas as colunas sob uma mesma condição (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

Tenho uma tabela no R com 96 colunas e 522 linhas e gostaria criar um filtro manter somente os valores que obedeçam à seguinte condição:

Para qualquer coluna os valores mantidos deverão ser a mediana de cada coluna & (valores >= a mediana de cada coluna + 20)

Por exemplo, a tabela:

```
A   B   C   D   F
100 49  15  40  60
34  15  14  14  50
14  13  12  13  30
9   12  9   12  2
8   2   8   12  1
```

Ficaria dessa forma:

```
A   B   C   D   F
100 49      40  60
34              50
14  13  12  13  30
```

Alguma sugestão de comando?

Comment: Os valores mantidos deverão *ser*  ou *estar entre* a mediana de cada coluna & (mediana de cada coluna + 20)?

Comment: Bem observado. Fiz a correção. Eu preciso manter a mediana e os valores 20 unidades acima da mediana.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Talvez o seguinte código resolva o problema.

```r
m <- sapply(dados, median)
i <- dados == m | dados >= m + 20
dados[!i] <- NA_real_
dados
#>     A  B  C  D  F
#> 1 100 49 NA 40 60
#> 2  34 NA NA NA 50
#> 3  NA NA 12 NA NA
#> 4  NA NA NA NA NA
#> 5  NA NA NA NA NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Dados

```r
dados <- "A   B   C   D   F
100 49  15  40  60
34  15  14  14  50
14  13  12  13  30
9   12  9   12  2
8   2   8   12  1"
dados <- read.table(text = dados, header = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Rui, o seu comando funcionou. Muito obrigado! Todavia, eu me expressei mal e gostaria de na verdade selecionar as medianas e os valores 20 unidades acima da mediana. Alguma sugestão de fórmula? Eu tentei "df2 == m & df2 >= m + 20", mas daí resulta tudo em falso, pois as duas condições são impossíveis ao mesmo tempo. Como eu estabeleço ou uma ou outra condição?

Comment: @Cristiano Basta mudar as condições e usar a disjunção `|` em vez da conjunção `&`.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado

Comment: Estranho! Percebi que o comando não funcionou exatamente como pretendido. De uma forma que eu não sei explicar, foram mantidos números que não correspondem às duas condições estabelecidas e também desapareceram números que estavam na condição. Tipo que o comando funcionou para uma parte da tabela e para outra não.